# erro 5 Invalid procedure call or argument when formating a cell on table creation

Tags: excel, vba

I have started to have several errors after formatting the cell on table creation(using vba). The idea is to format the first row when a table is created, after the first i believe excel will automatically format the row's below with the same format type. The errors are showing in the immediate window (check bellow on the code part for them)

I did not try much, mostly because i am unsure why this error is occurring. The vba formatting code is only being triggered after the table is created so it cannot be because there is no table at that time. I read already the error code support at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5 and i cannot understand what argument i am using that i should not... If i conduct a macro and change my self manually it will write a very similar code line.

```vb
Immediate window
criarTabela:5:Invalid procedure call or argument
novaLinha:5:Invalid procedure call or argument
But_Adic:5:Invalid procedure call or argument
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Butao_Adicionar_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim forceInput(2) As String
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim ctCheck As Boolean

    'Variaveis que indica as caixas de texto que teem ibrigatóriamente de ser preenchidas
    forceInput(0) = "Input_Nome"
    If Trim(Me.Input_Contacto2.Value) = "" Then
        forceInput(1) = "Input_Contacto1"
    Else
        forceInput(1) = "Input_Contacto1"
    End If
    forceInput(2) = IIf(Trim(Me.Input_Local.Value) = "", "Input_Local", "Input_Localidade")

    ctCheck = True

    'Forçar as caixas de texto indicadas nas variaveis acima a serem preenchidas ou o utilizador será alertádo
    For Each element In forceInput
        If Trim(Me(element).Value) = "" Then
            ctCheck = False
            Me(element).BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Colocar a caixa de texto verde
            Worksheets("Dados").Cells(1, 1).Value = Join(forceInput, ",")
        Else
            Me(element).BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'Colocar a caixa de texto branca
        End If
    Next element

    'Se a variavel ctCheck for true chamar a sub rotina novaLinha
    If ctCheck Then
        Call novaLinha
    End If

    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "But_Adic:" & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub

Sub novaLinha()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Dados")

    If Not ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Call criarTabela(ws)
    End If

    If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Dim newrow As ListRow

        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TabelaDados")
        Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        With newrow
            .Range(1) = Me.Input_ID.Value
            .Range(2) = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
            .Range(3) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm")
            criarBt .Range(4)
            .Range(5) = Me.Input_Nome.Value
            .Range(6) = Me.Input_Contacto1.Value & "|" & Me.Input_Contacto2.Value
        End With
    End If

    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "novaLinha:" & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub criarBt(cel As Range)
    Dim bt As Button

    Set bt = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(cel.Left, cel.Top, cel.Width, cel.Height)
    With bt
        .OnAction = "Createbutton"
        .Caption = "Hora fim"
        .Name = "HoraFim_" & cel.Row
    End With
End Sub

Sub criarTabela(ws)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tCell As Range
    Dim hdrRange As Range
    Dim ctHeader() As String
    Dim headerCt As Integer

    Const HEADERS As String = "ID,Data,H. inicial,H. final,Nome,Contactos"

    ctHeader = Split(HEADERS, ",")
    headerCt = UBound(ctHeader) + 1
    ' Coloca os valores de HEADERS nas colunas designádas em hdrRange
    Set hdrRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, headerCt))
    hdrRange.Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Split(HEADERS, ",")))

    ' Cria a tabela
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, hdrRange, , xlYes)

    With tbl
        .Name = "TabelaDados"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
        .Range.AutoFilter
        .Range.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter

        .Range("TabelaDados[ID]").NumberFormat = "0"
        .Range("TabelaDados[Data]").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
        .Range("TabelaDados[H. inicial]").NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
        .Range("TabelaDados[H. final]").NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
        .Range("TabelaDados[Nome]").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Range("TabelaDados[Contactos]").NumberFormat = "General"
    End With
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "criarTabela:" & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Since the error's are being given in 3 routines i place all 3 of them here. Hope it's not too much. The idea is to stop giving errors and as well understand the reason they happen.

Comment: `Sub criarTabela(ws)`  seems incorrect... what is `ws` supposed to be?  As you're using `Option Explicit` you have to declare everything.  For a Function, you would declare something like `function fdsa(ws as worksheet)`, then when calling `fdsa()` you would list `fdsa(Sheets(1))` or the like..

Comment: ohh i forgot to add there `As Worksheet` ... nice catch lol, but it never did any error because of that, weird ... but still that does not eliminate the errors

Comment: for what i can read in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat the use i am making wit the `NumberFormat` property  is correct. So i guess the error must be in some other place right ?

Comment: Well, an error 5 would mean that something being called isn't appropriate, be it syntax or that you're outside of the available range.  Are you able to specify which lines the errors are occuring to help narrow down?

Comment: Also, have you attempted to run the codes by commenting out the `on error resume next`?  that may be of benefit to where errors are occuring.

Comment: if i comment the lines where we set the cell format `.Range("TabelaDados[H. final]").NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"`all 3 errors stop giving. However in that case it not format the cell.
Other then that i cannot say nothing else to narrow down the mistake. I will uncomment more stuff to see if the errors stops from other place

Comment: I believe what will help the most is to let the native error message occur, then we can work on what isnt' being formatted.  It might just be a syntax issue or it might be that your range isn't where you think it is.

Comment: i did comment all `on error resume next` and now it gives a Microsoft Visual Basic error window with the same message error and the yellow lines point to the `NumberFormat`lines

Comment: Just tried all the 3 methods that i know to format an individual cell and after when testing all of them point the yellow line to it. `.Columns("A").NumberFormat = "0"`  , `.Range("A2").NumberFormat = "0"`, `.Range(Cells(2, 1)).NumberFormat = "0"` and `.Range("TabelaDados[ID]").NumberFormat = "0"`

Comment: I'll delete my answer to not give anyone the pretense that this has been answered... re-cap of the answer:  attempted `tbl.ListColumns().DataBody>Range.NumberFormat = ""` trying both the listcolumns `index` and the column name.  Neither seemed to rectify the issue.

Comment: did make a small macro code that creates the same error but it's only a 5 or 6 lines of code. Should i replace this code with that one to be easier and more readable ?

Comment: Please edit your post to have an "Edit" section where the new code is added, not removing the original scope.

Comment: i did place that new small code in the new answer .... Guess it was better

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out how to fix my issue.
Did make as well a small macro for people to test if.

However the lines making the error occur were change to something like this:

```
.Range(2, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

Above you can find the test code I made

```vb
Sub makeTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "ID"
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Date"

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:B1"), , xlYes)

    With tbl
        .Name = "DataTable"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
        .Range.AutoFilter
        .Range.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .Range.VerticalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter

        .Range(2, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
        .Range(2, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    End With
End Sub
```